# Что означает конструкция for(;;) без параметров?

Tags: c++, синтаксис

Что означает такая конструкция?

```
for(;;)
{
  //операторы
}
```

Понятно, что цикл `for`, но что с его параметрами?

Comment: вечный цикл? :-)

Comment: А зачем параметры? любой цикл for всегда можно развернуть в while. Смотрите. `for (A; B; C) {D;}` <=> `A; while (B) {D;C;}`. Любой из элементов можно пропустить. Если пропускаем B, то принимаем его за true. Ну, и мы всегда можем написать не блок `{...}`, а с `;`: `while (1); // вечный цикл`

Comment: по большому счёту, можно деже `for (A; B; C, D)`

Comment: Но это всего лишь расширение идеи использования оператора `,`. Ведь действительно можно тогда и `for (A1, A2; B; C1, C2)`.

Comment: @STIZZ, это так маскируют

    {
      Label:;
      ...
      goto Label;
    }

но, глубокий смысл в этом есть. 

С первого взгляда понятно (в случае for(;;){ }), что извне блока for(;;){ } нет переходов на его начало (иначе надо было бы искать все goto Label;).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Это **бесконечный цикл** (эквивалентно `while(true) {}`).  Иногда такое нужно. Выход из него обычно по `break`, или по `return`.

Comment: Часто также while(1){...}

Comment: @BuilderC, по сути, true эквивалентно 1, а False - 0. В машинной памяти они, кстати, так и представлены в виде чисел. Поэтому, раз нечего добавить, так лучше уж ничего не ляпать...

Comment: Жалко, что минусовать нельзя. 

>  true эквивалентно 1

Ага, это при учете того, что, скажем, `while (255){...}` будет себя вести так же :-)

Comment: всё просто:

    false = 0;
    true = !false;

Answer (score 6):

> но что с его параметрами?

они банально опущены, следовательно ничего не происходит в начале цикла, нет проверок окончания цикла, и нет блока описывающего действия, следовательно цикл будет работать эквивалентно конструкции

```
 while(true){...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю еще, что в цикле for и тело не является обязательным. Поэтому бывает и обратная ситуация: параметры есть, а тела - нет. Потому что все нужные операции уже в параметрах.

Вы удивитесь еще больше, но иногда имеет смысл даже такая конструкция:

```
do { make_me_happy(); } while(0)
```

Comment: Добавлю еще: иногда бывает полезно даже и без тела, и без параметров - for(;;);

Comment: Зачем? Зациклить основную программу, чтобы остались живы ее треды?

Comment: @VadimTukaev, бессмысленно. Чем тратить процессорное время, лучше попросить ОС «заморозить» главный поток до завершения дополнительных потоков.